# Nunit test case for website in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms, web, nunit

how to add website project reference to unit test project

Comment: there are three different questions here, stack-overflow is designed to target individual problems. Besides that We can’t help you with your problems without you telling us what you have tried. This question is to broad and you should split it out into smaller singular questions and go into detail about your problem.

Comment: About the third topic you can use NUnit as mentioned in the title

Comment: About the second topic, you can target the business logic, rather than the pages themselves.

Comment: About the first topic, as mentioned, you should test the logic rather than the pages, if unit testing is the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right click, like this:

Add the reference
[image: Add reference]

Add the project

[image: Reference the project]

And that's it.

Comment: For web application we can do like this but website type it's like that

Comment: can´t understand what do you mean

Comment: could you add images to your question? therefore it is more clear